# Program crashes when calling new operator (C++)

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm working my way through some tutorials I found on creating an ASCII game engine in C and writing my program in C++ to practice. I'm currently working on some stuff with allocating image data on the heap in the form of an Image struct (containing an int width, int height, and two char pointers to locations on the heap holding arrays of chars [width * height] in size)... however, I'm having some problems calling the new operator. The function where I'm allocating the memory for the struct itself, as well as its character and colour data, looks like this:

```
Image *allocateImage(int width, int height) {

Image *image;
image = new Image;

if (image == NULL)
    return NULL;

image->width = width;
image->height = height;
image->chars = new CHAR[width * height];
image->colours = new COL[width * height];

//image->colours = (CHAR*) PtrAdd(image->chars, sizeof(CHAR) + width * height);

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) { //initializes transparent image
    *(&image->chars + i) = 0;
    *(&image->colours + i) = 0;
}
return image;
}
```

The main function itself (where this function is called twice) looks like this:

```
int main() {
int x, y, offsetx, offsety;

DWORD i;

srand(time(0));

bool write = FALSE;

INPUT_RECORD *eventBuffer;

COLORREF palette[16] =
  {
        0x00000000, 0x00800000, 0x00008000, 0x00808000,
        0x00000080, 0x00800080, 0x00008080, 0x00c0c0c0,
        0x00808080, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x00ffff00,
        0x000000ff, 0x00ff00ff, 0x0000ffff, 0x00ffffff
  };

COORD bufferSize = {WIDTH, HEIGHT};

DWORD num_events_read = 0;

SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1};

COORD characterBufferSize = {WIDTH, HEIGHT};
COORD characterPosition = {0, 0};
SMALL_RECT consoleWriteArea = {0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1};

wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

SetConsoleTitle("Title!");
SetConsolePalette(palette, 8, 8, L"Sunkure Font");

SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wHnd, bufferSize);
SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, TRUE, &windowSize);

for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
    for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x) {
        consoleBuffer[x + WIDTH * y].Char.AsciiChar = (unsigned char)219;
        consoleBuffer[x + WIDTH * y].Attributes = FOREGROUND_BLUE;
    }
}

write = TRUE;

Image *sun_image = allocateImage(SUNW, SUNH);
Image *cloud_image = allocateImage(CLOUDW, CLOUDH);
setImage(sun_image, SUN.chars, SUN.colors);
setImage(cloud_image, Cloud.chars, Cloud.colours);
```

I can post more code if anyone feels it's necessary, but the program only reaches this point - in fact, a little before, as it crashes on the second call to allocateImage, at the point in the function where the new operator is called. The program has been working just fine until this point - the only recent additions have been the functions for allocation of image data on the heap (for creation of images with variable sizes) as well as deallocation (which isn't reached by this program). Since the program I'm learning from is written in C this is one place where looking at the source code won't help me, and Google's been not much help either. Can anyone point me to what's going wrong?

Comment: Image* image = new Image();   (add the parens)  - the initialization logic looks dubious, too, unless COL is a primitive type.

Comment: parens are optional when there are no parameters.

Comment: Sorry, should have added those defines - CHAR and COL are both defined as unsigned chars.

Comment: Post the code of your Image class (it's ctor should be taking care of most of the things you're doing in allocateImage, but that can be fixed once you have it working)

Comment: 1. `allocateImage` should be the constructor. 2. Don’t return a pointer, return an object. 3. Don’t check for `NULL` after `new`, it’s useless (`new` will **never** return `NULL`). You’re not doing it consistently anyway. 4. [Don’t use pointers, use C++ data structures.](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These lines

```
*(&image->chars + i) = 0;
*(&image->colours + i) = 0;
```

are dubious because `image` is already a pointer. A pointer to a pointer doesn't make sense here. Simply remove the `&`.

Since your actual code writes to Joe Random Address anything can happen. So it is not unusual that you thwart the memory subsystem and hence the next `new` call.

Comment: Even clearer is to change this to array notation as you're doing elsewhere, e.g.: image->chars[i] = 0;

Comment: Worked, thank you! I'm not even 100% sure why I had that there - as soon as I looked at it it was fairly clear what was going wrong but just didn't see it when I was looking on my own =/

Comment: Done! Not very used to StackOverflow, this is my first time posting a questions ;)